# Add arguments to last invocation of `find ... -exec $COMMAND {} +`

Tags: find

I'm generating ctags using something like the following line

```
find -iname '*.[hc]' -exec ctags -a --sort=no {} +
```

The result is that tags are not sorted. For that I'm using

```
sort -u -o tags tags
```

What I'm curious about, is it possible to do all of this in `find`? In other words, can I instruct `find` to use `--sort=no` for all **but** last invocation of ctags, when it would use `--sort=yes`?

The current way is sufficient (and `ctags` internally calls `sort -u -o $TAGFILE $TAGFILE` anyway) but I'm curious if this is possible.

Comment: Your current line should only invoke ctags once.

Comment: I do not agree. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05 : " The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded. ". On my reposiroty (20 year old system with multiple milions of LoC) ctags is executed 16 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `find` can't do it. If instead of `-exec {}` you use the classic print-to-`xargs` 
(and the filenames don't contain characters special to shell like space, dollarsign, or quotes, or you go to the trouble of protecting them) you can identify and "correct" the last group=line:

```
find -iname pattern | xargs echo ctags -a --sort=no | sed '$s/sort=no/sort=yes/' | sh
```

But as you implicitly ask, why bother when you can just run the `sort`?

Comment: heh I like it :) why bother? curiosity, was just interested if it's possible to do something like this. so, thanks :)